# Approaches for reducing rate of resource file growth as dialogs are enhanced/extended

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, dialog

As part of extending the functionality of a dialog in an old Windows WinAPI GUI application written in C, I was faced with once more adding multiple check boxes for each line of a six line data entry dialog. I just could not bear the hassle of repetitive resource file and source code file changes and decided to borrow a UI design approach from Java UIs of building up a UI from panes.

The Visual Studio tools, at least Visual Studio 2005, seem to discourage this approach and in this case I hand edited the resource file. Perhaps the resource editing tools of Visual Studio 2017 are more flexible.

*My question is what is an alternative to this approach that would seem to be as easy to do and would better fit with the Visual Studio philosophy.*

I am also wondering about the downside of this approach.

This approach seems unusual for a Visual Studio C WinAPI GUI application which troubles me. I can't claim to be especially innovative so I wonder what I am missing as the approach seems to work well at least when doing hand edits of the resource file.

I am considering doing another iteration in which I move the list of controls for each line that is repeated into the modeless dialog box template as well and just having the original dialog be a stack of 6 static windows, one for each line.

Benefits of this approach was fewer defines and being able to reuse defines. It was also easier to insert the new functionality into the existing dialog behavior source code though that was mostly because these were just simple auto check boxes.

The one issue I see is using the Visual Studio tools after doing this change. However this particular application's resource file doesn't work well with the Visual Studio resource editing tools anyway.

This approach has already had a payback when I needed to add some additional checkboxes to the modeless dialog template. The resource file changes I had to do to was to add the additional checkboxes to the new dialog template and adjust the original dialog size, the modeless dialog size, and the sizes of the static windows to make everything visible.

**The Implementation**

The alternative I have implemented is to:

- create a dialog template with the set of checkboxes
- modify the dialog template style of the modeless dialog to WS_CHILD
- create a static window on each of the six lines of the original dialog for the new dialog template
- place an instance of the modeless dialog box into the static window on each line

The new version of the dialog looks like [image: screen shot of new version of the data entry dialog]
When the original dialog is displayed, the handler for the init dialog message creates a set of six modeless dialogs, one for each of the newly added static windows with the parent window for the dialogs being the static window. This places the modeless dialog into the static window and when the static window moves so does the modeless dialog.

All six of the modeless dialogs use the same dialog message handler. The message handler doesn't handle any messages itself.

The modeless dialog template is:

```
IDD_A170_DAYS DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 240, 20
STYLE  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "Ovr",IDD_A170_STR1,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,5,1,25,10
    CONTROL         "AND",IDD_A170_STR2,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,35,1,40,10
    CONTROL         "S",IDD_A170_CAPTION1,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,75,1,20,10
    CONTROL         "M",IDD_A170_CAPTION2,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,100,1,20,10
    CONTROL         "T",IDD_A170_CAPTION3,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,125,1,20,10
    CONTROL         "W",IDD_A170_CAPTION4,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,150,1,20,10
    CONTROL         "T",IDD_A170_CAPTION5,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,175,1,20,10
    CONTROL         "F",IDD_A170_CAPTION6,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,195,1,20,10
    CONTROL         "S",IDD_A170_CAPTION7,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,220,1,20,10
END
```

and the main dialog with the static windows is:

```
IDD_A170 DIALOG DISCARDABLE  2, 17, 530, 190
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Set Sales Code Restriction Table of PLU (AC 170)"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "Address              (PLU Sales Code)",IDD_A170_CAPTION1,14,10,64,20
    LTEXT           "Date",IDD_A170_CAPTION2,86,14,28,12
    LTEXT           "Day of week",IDD_A170_CAPTION3,115,10,33,21
    LTEXT           "Start hour",IDD_A170_CAPTION4,153,10,20,18
    LTEXT           "Minute",IDD_A170_CAPTION5,182,14,26,12
    LTEXT           "End hour",IDD_A170_CAPTION6,217,10,20,18
    LTEXT           "Minute",IDD_A170_CAPTION7,245,14,26,12
    LTEXT           "Override/Type",IDC_STATIC,290,14,50,12
    LTEXT           "Days To Restrict",IDC_STATIC,390,14,100,12
    LTEXT           "",IDD_A170_STR1,8,34,74,12                     // first control on line 1
    EDITTEXT        IDD_A170_DATE1,87,33,18,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    SCROLLBAR       IDD_A170_DATESPIN1,104,33,8,12,SBS_VERT
    EDITTEXT        IDD_A170_WEEK1,119,33,18,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    SCROLLBAR       IDD_A170_WEEKSPIN1,136,33,8,12,SBS_VERT
    EDITTEXT        IDD_A170_SHOUR1,151,33,18,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    SCROLLBAR       IDD_A170_SHOURSPIN1,168,33,8,12,SBS_VERT
    EDITTEXT        IDD_A170_SMINUTE1,183,33,18,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    SCROLLBAR       IDD_A170_SMINUTESPIN1,200,33,8,12,SBS_VERT
    EDITTEXT        IDD_A170_EHOUR1,214,33,18,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    SCROLLBAR       IDD_A170_EHOURSPIN1,231,33,8,12,SBS_VERT
    EDITTEXT        IDD_A170_EMINUTE1,246,33,18,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    SCROLLBAR       IDD_A170_EMINUTESPIN1,263,33,8,12,SBS_VERT
    LTEXT           "D1",IDD_A170_DAYS_1,281,33,240,20             // static window to contain the modeless dialog box from the template IDD_A170_DAYS above
    //   .. repeated sequence for 5 more lines
    CONTROL         "MDC 298 - Sales Restriction Type is AND",IDD_A170_MDC_PLU5_ADR,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,9,140,170,9
    LTEXT           "[Address :  1 - 6, Date : 0 - 31",IDD_A170_CAPTION8,9,154,99,9
    LTEXT           "Day of week : 0 - 7 (1 - Sunday, 7 - Saturday)]",IDD_A170_CAPTION9,110,154,167,9
    LTEXT           "[Hour : 0 - 24, Minute : 0 - 59 (For 0:00, enter 24:00)]",IDD_A170_CAPTION10,9,168,167,9
    PUSHBUTTON      "&Ok",IDOK,285,154,48,20
    PUSHBUTTON      "&Cancel",IDCANCEL,345,154,48,20
END
```

You may notice that I just reused some of the defines in the new modeless dialog box that were already being used in the original dialog box. I was able to do so because control identifiers are specific to the dialog box itself. So using the same define in different dialog boxes does not cause a problem since the use of `GetDlgItem()` to obtain the window handle of a control within a dialog box requires the window handle of a specific dialog instance.

I then created a set of helper functions that handle an instance of the modeless dialog.

```
static struct {
    int   iId;
    HWND  hWnd;
} A170DlgTabs[10] = { {0, 0} };

// modeless dialog box message handler which has nothing to do but the
// WinAPI requires it.
BOOL    WINAPI  A170DlgChildProc(HWND hDlg, UINT wMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        return FALSE;
}

void  A170ModeLessChildDialogClear ()
{
    memset (A170DlgTabs, 0, sizeof(A170DlgTabs));
}

HWND A170ModeLessChildDialog (HWND hParentWnd, int nCmdShow, int iId)
{
    int   i;
    HWND  hWnd = DialogCreation(hResourceDll/*hActInst*/,  //RPH 4-23-03 Multilingual
                                   MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDD_A170_DAYS),
                                   hParentWnd,
                                   A170DlgChildProc);
    hWnd && ShowWindow (hWnd, nCmdShow);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(A170DlgTabs)/sizeof(A170DlgTabs[0]); i++) {
        if (A170DlgTabs[i].hWnd == 0) {
            A170DlgTabs[i].iId = iId;
            A170DlgTabs[i].hWnd = hWnd;
            break;
        }
    }

    return hWnd;
}

HWND A170ModeLessChildDialogFind (int iId)
{
    int   i;
    HWND  hWnd = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(A170DlgTabs)/sizeof(A170DlgTabs[0]); i++) {
        if (A170DlgTabs[i].iId == iId) {
            hWnd = A170DlgTabs[i].hWnd;
            break;
        }
    }

    return hWnd;
}

USHORT A170ModeLessChildDialogSettings (int iId)
{
    int     i;
    USHORT  iBits = 0, kBits = 1;
    HWND hWnd = A170ModeLessChildDialogFind (iId);

    // least significant byte contains the bit mask for the days of the week.
    // the next higher byte contains the indicators for the override type or
    // whether MDC 298 is to be overriden or not.
    for (i = IDD_A170_CAPTION1; i <= IDD_A170_CAPTION7; i++, (kBits <<= 1)) {
        iBits |= IsDlgButtonChecked (hWnd, i) ? kBits : 0;
    }

    iBits |= iBits ? RESTRICT_WEEK_DAYS_ON : 0;

    iBits |= IsDlgButtonChecked(hWnd, IDD_A170_STR1) ? KBITS_RESTRICT_OVERRIDE_ANDOR : 0;
    iBits |= IsDlgButtonChecked(hWnd, IDD_A170_STR2) ? KBITS_RESTRICT_OVERRIDE_AND : 0;

    return iBits;
}


USHORT A170ModeLessChildDialogSettingsSetMask (int iId, USHORT  usMask)
{
    int     i;
    USHORT  k = 1;
    HWND    hWnd = A170ModeLessChildDialogFind (iId);

    CheckDlgButton(hWnd, IDD_A170_STR1, (usMask & KBITS_RESTRICT_OVERRIDE_ANDOR) ? TRUE : FALSE);
    CheckDlgButton(hWnd, IDD_A170_STR2, (usMask & KBITS_RESTRICT_OVERRIDE_AND) ? TRUE : FALSE);

    for (i = IDD_A170_CAPTION1; i <= IDD_A170_CAPTION7; i++, (k <<= 1)) {
        CheckDlgButton(hWnd, i, (usMask & k) ? TRUE : FALSE);
    }

    return usMask;
}
```

Comment: This is not an unreasonable design. One additional thing you might want to do is change the control IDs inside the modal dialog so that you don't have ID collisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition made taking this approach to creating components from dialog templates which are then used to build a GUI easier.

I did this rough, proof of concept exercise using the About dialog that is automatically generated by the creation of a new Windows Desktop Application project since it was handy.

This was a simple component being expressed in a dialog template and that simplicity may make this proof of concept misleading.

I started with an initial Windows Desktop Application skeleton created as a new project. I then made the following modifications to the About dialog that is automatically generated with a New project. I was able to use the IDE and Resource Editor without doing any hand editing of the resource file.

The steps were as follows:

- use the Resource Editor to modify the existing About dialog and create a new modeless dialog
- add a new class to manage the new modeless dialog
- modify the About dialog message handler to use the new class

Modifications to the dialog resources using the Resource Editor was fairly straightforward:

- modify the automatically generated About dialog by making it larger and adding two static text windows in a column
- specify actual control identifiers for each static text box added to the About dialog so that they could be referenced with `GetDlgItem()`, an important step as the IDE does not assign usable control identifiers by default to static windows
- created a new dialog template using the Resource Editor after switching to Resource View
- modified a couple of Appearance attributes in the Properties list of the dialog box to change the dialog to a modeless dialog with no border
- added the checkboxes to the new dialog using the Resource Editor and removed the default buttons

The source code changes were also fairly straightforward as this is a simple control.

The new About dialog box looks like this. I added two static windows to the About dialog after making it larger. Each of the static windows has its own instance of the new dialog template based control. Notice that the size of the dialog template is larger than the size of the static windows which results in clipping of the dialog template to the display area of the static window.

[image: screenshot of modified About dialog]

### The Details of What Was Done

**Create and Modify the Dialog Styles**

Using Resource View I added a new dialog. I clicked on the new dialog to bring it up in the Resource Editor. Then I modified the initial modal dialog template by changing the `border` attribute and the `style` attribute along with removing the default buttons the IDE added when it first created the dialog template, I turned the dialog template into a modeless dialog suitable for putting into a static window container.

[image: screenshot of Properties] 
[image: screenshots of before and after of new dialog]

**Create the Code for the Behavior**

I then created a class, `CDialogChild` to manage this new modeless dialog with the following source:

```
#pragma once

#include "resource.h"

class CDialogChild
{
private:
    // static shared by all instances of this class
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    enum {DIALOG_ID = IDD_DIALOG1};
    static const UINT idCheckBox[3];    // identifiers for the controls of the modeless dialog.

    // management data for each modeless dialog instance created.
    HINSTANCE m_hinst;       // handle to the instance resources
    HWND      m_hWnd;        // handle to the modeless dialog window
    HWND      m_hParent;     // handle to the parent of the modeless dialog, usually static window

    // operational data displayed and captured by this modeless dialog
    // this is the data for the various controls we have in the dialog template.
    bool      bCheckBox[3] = { false, false, false };

public:
    CDialogChild();
    ~CDialogChild();
    bool GetCheck(int iIndex);    // for reading checkbox value
    void GetCheckFinal(void);     // for capturing final checkbox states
    bool SetCheck(int iIndex, bool bValue);   // for writing checkbox value
    void SetCheckInitial(void);               // for setting the initial checkbox states.

    HWND Create(HWND hParent, HINSTANCE hinst);

};
```

with an implementation of:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CDialogChild.h"

const UINT CDialogChild::idCheckBox[3] = { IDC_CHECK1, IDC_CHECK2, IDC_CHECK3 };


CDialogChild::CDialogChild()
{
}


CDialogChild::~CDialogChild()
{
}

HWND CDialogChild::Create(HWND hParent, HINSTANCE hinst)
{
    // called to create the modeless dialog using the dialog resource in the
    // specified resource file instance. the hParent is the container we are
    // going to put this modeless dialogbox into.
    m_hinst = hinst;
    m_hParent = hParent;
    m_hWnd = CreateDialog(hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DIALOG_ID), hParent, (DLGPROC)CDialogChild::WndProc);

    ShowWindow(m_hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    return m_hWnd;
}

bool CDialogChild::GetCheck(int iIndex)
{
    if (iIndex > 0 && iIndex < sizeof(bCheckBox) / sizeof(bCheckBox[0])) {
        iIndex = 0;
    }

    bCheckBox [iIndex] = IsDlgButtonChecked(m_hWnd, idCheckBox[iIndex]);
    return bCheckBox [iIndex];
}

bool CDialogChild::SetCheck(int iIndex, bool bValue)
{
    if (iIndex > 0 && iIndex < sizeof(bCheckBox) / sizeof(bCheckBox[0])) {
        iIndex = 0;
    }

    CheckDlgButton (m_hWnd, idCheckBox[iIndex], bValue);
    bCheckBox[iIndex] = bValue;
    return bCheckBox [iIndex];
}

void CDialogChild::GetCheckFinal(void)
{
    for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < sizeof(bCheckBox) / sizeof(bCheckBox[0]); iIndex++) {
        bCheckBox[iIndex] = IsDlgButtonChecked(m_hWnd, idCheckBox[iIndex]);
    }
}

void CDialogChild::SetCheckInitial(void)
{
    for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < sizeof(bCheckBox) / sizeof(bCheckBox[0]); iIndex++) {
        CheckDlgButton(m_hWnd, idCheckBox[iIndex], bCheckBox[iIndex]);
    }
}

// CDialogChild class Windows message procedure to handle any messages sent
// to a modeless dialog window. This simple example there is not much to do.
LRESULT CALLBACK CDialogChild::WndProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

**Use the New Control in a Dialog**

Finally I modified the `About` dialog to use the new dialog template based control. The first thing was to add the static windows to the About dialog template to provide containers for the new control which provided the placement for where I wanted the control instances to be.

Next I added the handling source code to use the new dialog template based control in the modified About dialog.

```
// other source code from the Windows Desktop Application main window handler
// is above this. We are only modifying the About dialog code which is at the
// bottom of the source file.

#include "CDialogChild.h"

CDialogChild myAbout1;
CDialogChild myAbout2;

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        myAbout1.Create(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC4), hInst);
        myAbout1.SetCheckInitial();
        myAbout2.Create(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC5), hInst);
        myAbout2.SetCheckInitial();
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK) {
                myAbout1.GetCheckFinal();
                myAbout2.GetCheckFinal();
            }
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```